# Trendline through origin in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have seen other mention using the LINEST function to force a trendline to pass through the origin in Google Sheets, but how?

I do not know anything about computers or the language google sheets uses, but instead of [calculate_b] I tried entering [FALSE], [FALSE, b=0], and [b=0]. None of these worked :(

Comment: Reference to [LINEST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083448/1330560) on StackOverflow.

Comment: YouTube showing use of LINEST: [Making a Trendline with a Y-Intercept of Zero Using Google Sheets](https://youtu.be/ShVA3XCJo_E?si=P8ve_daVIZczMXhe) 5 minutes.

Comment: Welcome _I do not know anything about computers or the language google sheets uses_ Under the circumstances I’m not sure of your expectations for this question. Would you please edit your question to include your sample data in the body of the question.